# How to use stacked Font Awesome icons with p:menuitem?

Tags: css, primefaces, font-awesome, jsf-2.2

I'm using Font Awesome PrimeFaces integration (with regular icons) and it works great.

Now I'm trying to make it work with [stacked icons](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#stacked) in the following way:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
   <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

In my code example where I use PrimeFaces I have something like

```
<p:submenu expanded="true" label="Request" styleClass="groupmenu">
    <p:menuitem value="Annual Forecast" outcome="coursesList.xhtml" icon="fa fa-pencil" />
    <p:menuitem value="Forecast History" outcome="annualList.xhtml" icon="fa fa-eye"  />
</p:submenu>
```

and I'd like to replace `fa-pencil` and `fa-eye` with some stacked icons

How can I achieve it?
Thank you

Comment: i believe your approach is wrong. If you use Font Awesome Stacked Icons, then both eye and pencil will be visible. Is that what you want? Try this:  
`<p:submenu expanded="true" label="Request" styleClass="groupmenu">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-eye fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-stack-1x"></i>
        </span>
    </p:submenu>`

Comment: Yes, is that what I want. Eye and pencil together is a nonsense, but a pencil stacked with a [fa-square-o](http://fontawesome.io/icon/square-o/) icon is nice. Btw your solution crashes `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions cannot be cast to org.primefaces.model.menu.MenuElement`

Comment: i need to know what is the architecture of your setup. I have added static html, but it seems your structure is different. Also, do you still need a solution for the problem? It will help if you can provide a working prototype on codepen so I can debug it

Comment: JSF 2.2, facelets, primefaces 6.1.RC1, Glassfish 4.1. Is a busy period but if I have a minute I will post a prototype. Thank you very much, your help is really appreciated.